# Firebase authentication - I get onVerificationCompleted callback 3s after getting onCodeSent

Tags: android, firebase-authentication

On one device, when I attempt to authenticate with Firebase on Android using a phone number, I get two callbacks - onCodeSent and then, 3s later, onVerificationCompleted. My code:

```
fun verifyPhone(
    phoneNumber: String,
    activity: Activity,
    authCallbacks: PhoneAuthProvider.OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks
) {
    PhoneAuthProvider.getInstance().verifyPhoneNumber(
        phoneNumber,
        AUTH_TIMEOUT_SEC,
        TimeUnit.SECONDS,
        activity,
        authCallbacks
    )
}
```

authCallbacks are as described here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/phone-auth

The problem has been so far discovered on only one device - other devices don't get `onVerificationCompleted` at all - only onCodeSent.

```
 2020-12-03 18:45:56.343 2820-2820/com.project.name
 D/EnterPhoneViewModel$authCallbacks: onCodeSent
 2020-12-03 18:45:59.232 2820-2820/com.project.name
 D/EnterPhoneViewModel$authCallbacks: onVerificationCompleted
```

There are no other user or program actions between the callbacks, except for switching to a new fragment, where user waits for the SMS code.
Note that the callback comes to the same ViewModel, even though I have already moved on to another fragment (and its own ViewModel) on account of receiving onCodeSent. That messes up the execution flow and occasionally causes my code to crash.
Should the callbacks be called like this? If so, then I guess one way to handle is would be to access the EnterPhoneViewModel also from the EnterCodeFragment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely this is due to the code being auto-verified. From the Firebase documentation on [sending a verification code](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/phone-auth#send-a-verification-code-to-the-users-phone):

> ```
> mCallbacks = new PhoneAuthProvider.OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks() {    
>    @Override
>    public void onVerificationCompleted(PhoneAuthCredential credential) {
>        // This callback will be invoked in two situations:
>        // 1 - Instant verification. In some cases the phone number can be instantly
>        //     verified without needing to send or enter a verification code.
>        // 2 - Auto-retrieval. On some devices Google Play services can automatically
>        //     detect the incoming verification SMS and perform verification without
>        //     user action.
>        Log.d(TAG, "onVerificationCompleted:" + credential);
>
>        signInWithPhoneAuthCredential(credential);
>    }
> ```

So repeated for emphasis:

> **On some devices Google Play services can automatically
> detect the incoming verification SMS and perform verification without
> user action.**

There is no guarantee that the feature will work on all devices with Google Play Services, but if it works it prevents the user from manually having to look up en enter the code.

Comment: Indeed, this looks like the case - I must have missed the second scenario. Unusual, since I will then have to break the normal fragment flow and just move the user from the Enter Code screen to the success screen without any action. Even worse - what if he managed to click the back arrow already? The control is in the EnterPhoneFragment, but it's not clear which fragment is on top of the stack.