# Force the verificationComplete callback

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, authentication

Im using firebase auth to login users in my app.

Im seeing that there is a way to use sms in order to verify phone numbers and create users.

The documentation says that you can autocomplete your input by using [verificationComplete callback.](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/flutter/phone-auth#testing)

The package that im using is [pinput and the readme says the same](https://pub.dev/packages/pinput#sms-autofill)

I've tried multiple times loggin by using verifyPhoneNumber as is explained in the documentation but never i never reached verificationComplete

In pinput you can use *androidSmsAutofillMethod* argument to set if you want to consent or do nothing, but when i use *AndroidSmsAutofillMethod.smsUserConsentApi* the app crashes (maybe tahts why they dont recomment you to do that in the documentation)

The problem is that i never get verificationComplete callback, only codeSent is reached.

There is a way force verificationComplete running?

Comment: It works only some some Android versions as stated in the firebase docs >>> " verificationCompleted
This handler will only be called on Android devices which support automatic SMS code resolution.

When the SMS code is delivered to the device, Android will automatically verify the SMS code without requiring the user to manually input the code. "

Comment: So there is no way i can force this behaivor or a list of devices where verificationComplete runs?

Comment: No, not all devices support auto verification as  mentioned here => https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65162554/firebase-authentication-i-get-onverificationcompleted-callback-3s-after-gettin

You have to handle both scenarios : auto verification and manual...

I don't know if there's a specific list of devices it works on but you could dig around in free time!